# ReactJS writing stateless function comments

Tags: javascript, reactjs, code-documentation

What is the recommended way of writing comments for ReactJS stateless functions?

Let say I have the following code:

```
export const LoginForm = ({ submitting, handleSubmit }) => (
  <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(submit)}> ...(code)... </form>
));
```

How should documentation comment look like?

My first idea was:

```
/**
 * Form for user login
 * @param {bool} submitting Shows if form submitting is in progress
 * @param {function} handleSubmit Form submit callback function
 */
```

But this is not correct as `submitting` and `handleSubmit` are not real params of the `LoginForm` function. They are just keys of the `props` parameter.
On the other hand documenting `props` as the parameter of `LoginForm` seems to be pointless because every react component has `props` as a parameter and the props keys are most important part of the function.

Are there any official guidelines? (I didn't find any)

---

#### EDIT

I have also `PropTypes` defined:

```
LoginForm.propTypes = {
  submitting: PropTypes.bool,
  handleSubmit: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};
```

Maybe this is the place for props related documentation? If so how should it look like? Is there any standard for that?

Comment: I think that PropTypes would be perfered.. but not sure

Comment: Yeah of course I have PropTypes defined but this is not real documentation as there is no description provided, only property type. Maybe I should document PropTypes? If so how this should look like.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can specify `props` object before property name:

```js
/**
 * Form for user login
 * @param {object} props Component props
 * @param {bool} props.submitting Shows if form submitting is in progress
 * @param {function} props.handleSubmit Form submit callback function
 */
export const LoginForm = ({ submitting, handleSubmit }) => (
  <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(submit)}> ...(code)... </form>
));
```

For more info see [@param](https://code.google.com/archive/p/jsdoc-toolkit/wikis/TagParam.wiki) wiki page in `Parameters With Properties` section.

Comment: What about the `@return` type?

Comment: You can add something like `@returns {JSX.Element} Component template`

Answer (score 9):

I know I am almost 3 years late to this party. Just adding for reference. One could do this:

```
/**
 * @typedef {Object<string, any>} Props
 * @property {boolean} submitting Shows if form submitting is in progress
 * @property {function} handleSubmit Form submit callback function
 */

/** 
 * Form for user login
 *
 * @type {import('react').FunctionComponentElement<Props>}
 */
export const LoginForm = ({ submitting, handleSubmit }) => (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(submit)}> ...(code)... </form>
);
```

For brevity, one could also do:

```
/**
 * Form for user login
 *
 * @type {import('react').FunctionComponentElement<{
       submitting: boolean,
       handleSubmit: function
    }>}
 */
export const LoginForm = ({ submitting, handleSubmit }) => (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(submit)}> ...(code)... </form>
);
```

If Typescript is enabled in your IDE, you could avoid declaring prop-types altogether with this setup.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is [jsdoc-react-proptypes](https://github.com/dxinteractive/jsdoc-react-proptypes), used like this:

```
SomeComponent.propTypes = {
  /** Function to run after animation completes. */
  onStop: PropTypes.func
};
```

This creates a "Properties" documentation section for the class that includes what you'd expect, roughly:

```
Name    Type Attributes  Description
onStop       <optional>  Function to run after animation completes.
```

I'm not sure why the `Type` doesn't show up; it's a pretty rough-shod library, but I had the same question, found this, and will have to work on cleaning it up some.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use this:

```
 * @property {function(argType1, argType2, argTypeN): void} handleSubmit - The handleSubmit Form submit callback function
```

And void in return type can be replaced by any data type like number or string.

Answer (score 0):

Defining an interface for each of my functional components and doing the documentation on that worked for me. For example:

```
interface IHeaderButtons {
    /**
     * IRI of the item that the header buttons are for
     */
    iri: string
}

/**
 * Display the Search and "View in STEADY" buttons for a term/class/etc.
 * @returns {React.FC<IHeaderButtons>} React Functional Component
 */
const HeaderButtons: React.FC<IHeaderButtons> = ({iri}) => {
    // ...
}
```

Visual Studio Code at least is able to generate intellisense based on this:
[image]