# How to document React functional components using Jsdocs and TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, document, jsdoc, react-functional-component

Given this

```
type LocationWeather = {
  name: string;
  temperature: number;
};

type IndexProp = {
  savedLocationsWeather: LocationWeather[];
  favoriteLocationWeather: LocationWeather;
};


function Index({ savedLocationsWeather, favoriteLocationWeather }: IndexProp)
```

What should the documentation look like?

My first approach was:

```
/**
 * Home page displaying weather details of saved locations and favorite location
 * @param {object} props Component props
 * @param {LocationWeather[]} props.savedLocationsWeather Weather details of saved locations
 * @param {LocationWeather} props.favoriteLocationWeather Weather details of favorite location
 * @return {TSX.Element}
 */
```

But:

1. I'm not sure if that's the correct way to specify the Array type of savedLocationsWeather as in

   `* @param {Array} props.savedLocationsWeather Weather details of saved locations`
2. I'm also not sure it's correct to specify LocationWeather as a jsdoc type, as in

   `* @param {Locationweather} props.favoriteLocationWeather Weather details of favorite location`
3. Is there even such a thing as a TSX.Element type, as in

   `* @return {TSX.Element}`

Finally, should I define PropTypes [as done here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38717783/reactjs-writing-stateless-function-comments)?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? I have the same question.